# Create nested directories in rust

Tags: rust

I'm working on a small application to organize my photos with the exif data in the jpeg file.  Most importantly I want the date.  I should be able to run this on a directory of jpegs.

I want my directory structure to be:

```
yyyy/
   yyyy-mm-dd/
      photos
```

I can create the parent directory (yyyy) but I'm not sure how to create the child directory (yyyy-mm-dd) within it.

The most obvious solution to me was to write this:

```
    let child_dir_name = format!("{}-0{}-0{}", &year, &month, &day);
    let parent_dir_name = format!("{}", &year);
    let path = (parent_dir_name/child_dir_name);
    fs::create_dir(path);
```

But this doesn't work, for obvious reasons.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, still new to Rust so any references/tips would be nice too.

EDIT:  I want to use the variable names as the directory names so

```
fs::create_dir_all(parent_path/child_path);
```

returns an error: `cannot divide &path by &path`

Comment: Unless it's a throwaway script (in which case you shouldn't be using Rust) never use strings when a [richer datatype exists](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html).

Comment: Thanks @JaredSmith But that doesn't exactly answer my question.  I updated my question to hopefully make things more clear.

Comment: Did you read the linked duplicate? Or the link to the standard library I posted? Just keep pushing the directories on to the Path/PathBuf (which has the advantage of being more portable across operating systems) or even pass the full path as a string to the Path::new or PathBuf::from constructors.

Comment: Sorry @JaredSmith I just tried again and it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::fs::create_dir_all` to create all the directories in a path. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.create_dir_all.html

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that Rust is considering the slash between the two variable names as a divide operator.

You can fix it by replacing `(parent_dir_name/child_dir_name)` with `format!("{}/{}", &parent_dir_name, &child_dir_name)`

Additionally you could give this string to `Path::new()` (with `use std::path::Path;`) to make this code OS-independant.

Also, as noted by others, to create directories recursively, you will need to use `std::fs::create_dir_all` instead of `std::fs::create_dir`